# how to get select value from select list array in jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML CODE

```
<select class="form-control" name="min_select[]">
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

JQuery Code

```
var val1[];
$('select[name="min_select[]"] option:selected').each(function() {
val1.push($(this).val());
});
```

when i run this code I get empty val array

Comment: is this a `select` with multiple attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration array syntax is in correct.Please check the below code

```
 var val1=[]; 
 $('select[name="min_select[]"] option:selected').each(function() {
  val1.push($(this).val());
 });
```

Answer (score 12):

This will also work

```
var  val1= $("select[name=\'min_select[]\']").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
```

Comment: That it is, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control min-select" name="min_select[]">
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var values = [];
$("select.min-select").each(function(i, sel){
    var selectedVal = $(sel).val();
    values.push(selectedVal);
});
```

Is min_select[] a multiple choice select?

Comment: min_select[] is not a multiple select.

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected value, whether it is multiselect or single select, use jQuery [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

If it is a multiselect, it will return an array of the selected values.

See [jsfiddle for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/txk25c4c/). Check console log